# jQuery, use "this" with dynamic selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to use jQuery to select a dynamic element on the page by using its class name + this. here is my code :

```
$('form').on('keyup', '.dynamicGenInput', this, function(ev){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

What is the proper syntax for this situation?

Comment: I read your question a few times and I'm still confused one what you're trying to do - could you elaborate?

Comment: Well you can not use jQuery to select an element that is added to the page dynamically after it loads. I am adding multiple elements with the same class to the page post page load. I need to use "on" to select said elements. I would like to combine it with "this" to select only the target dynamic element, then I will hide only that individual selected element in key up.

Comment: And sorry I copied the wrong text into my question, I edited it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is create a "delegated" event, like so:

```
$('form').on('keyup', '.dynamicGenInput', function(ev){
});
```

This will bind a `keyup` event to *all* `<form>` elements (that exist at the time).  When it's triggered, jQuery will check to see if the `keyup` event *actually* happened on a `.dynamicGenInput` element (that's a child of a `<form>`).  If so, then the bound function will run.

Inside of the function, you have access to the element triggered.

```
$('form').on('keyup', '.dynamicGenInput', function(ev){
    // `this` (or `ev.target`) is the .dynamicGenInput element you triggered
});
```